# Calling Subroutines and values in a User Defined Function (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I would be grateful if someone help in what is probably a simple solution.  Below a have a short code for User Defined Function in excel.
I am naming columns (in a large spreadsheet) to to calculate in `SUMIFS` calculation.  If I want to have the same columns named and use the variables `WRITEOFF1` and `WRITEOFF`" in another User Defined Function, how can I do that?  I have tried set the names of the column in a subroutine (in the same VBA Project and Module) and then tried to call the subroutine, but looks like I can not pass the names to another Function.

Can someone help with a solution?

Many thanks in advance.

---

```
Public Function WRITEOFF(rev_date As Variant) As Variant

  Application.Volatile (True)

  Set Order_Type = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$D:$D")
  Set Final_Price = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$H:$H")
  Set PaidAlt = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$I:$I")
  Set Excl_Rev = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$K:$K")
  Set PAmount1 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$O:$O")
  Set First_PD = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$Q:$Q")
  Set PMethod1 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$R:$R")
  Set PAmount2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$T:$T")
  Set PayDate2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$V:$V")
  Set PMethod2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$W:$W")
  Set PAmount3 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$Y:$Y")
  Set PayDate3 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$AA:$AA")
  Set PMethod3 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$AB:$AB")
  Set PAmount4 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$AD:$AD")
  Set PayDate4 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$AF:$AF")
  Set PMethod4 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$AG:$AG")
  Set Vstatus = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DL:$DL")
  Set Team = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DO:$DO")


        WRITEOFF1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            PAmount1 _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , First_PD, rev_date _
            , PMethod1, "Write Off")

        WRITEOFF2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            PAmount2 _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , PayDate2, rev_date _
            , PMethod2, "Write Off")

        WRITEOFF3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            PAmount3 _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , PayDate3, rev_date _
            , PMethod3, "Write Off")

        WRITEOFF4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            PAmount4 _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , PayDate4, rev_date _
            , PMethod4, "Write Off")

            WRITEOFF = WRITEOFF1 + WRITEOFF2 + WRITEOFF3 + WRITEOFF4
End Function
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run this? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Hi Jmax,The Function works, and I want to use the range names in this function and the values for WRITEOFF1 and WRITEOFF2 in another Function.  Rather than retyping all the code again, I am looking to see if I can recall the range names and the two values.  Is that possible?

Comment: Not quite understanding what you are looking for. You want to pass the named range name to another UDF? Why don't you just add the name as a parameter and enter it when you enter the formula? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I apologise, I am obviously not explaining myself properly.  In the above UDF "WRITEOFF", I define WRITEOFF as the sum of WRITEOFF1,2,3 and 4.  I would like to use the value of WRITEOFF1 in another UDF say called "ANOTHERWRITEOFF".  Is that possible or do I need to recalcuate WRITEOFF1 in the "ANOTHERWRITEOFF" UDF again.  I hope that is more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create these as Named Ranges, which would preserve them across functions but also would expose them as Ranges you can work with directly on the Worksheet.

Insert Named Ranges from the Formula ribbon, Name Manager, New:

[image: Name Manager]

In VBA, you refer to them like:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Order_Type)
```

On the worksheet, you can also refer to them in a cell:

`=(Sum(Order_Type))` or `=VLOOKUP("Steve",Order_Type,2,False)`, etc.

If you prefer not to use named ranges, set the variables as Public, then, within the Function, call on a subroutine to assign the ranges:

```
Public Order_Type As Range
Public Final_Price As Range

Function MyFunction()

'Call procedure to set the public variables
SetPublicVars

'Perform your function
MyFunction = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Order_Type)

End Function

Private Sub SetPublicVars()

Set Order_Type = Sheets(1).Range("D:D")
Set Final_Price = Sheets(1).Range("H:H")


End Sub
```